# I need to modify a file in ksh script using sed but not all the lines?

Tags: file, sed, sh, ksh

I have a file.pc (Pro c) that have some compatible problems with linux when passed from windows. So i tried to create a script to formalize the document in the format i need, but, i have encountered a problem with the substitution of `//` comments. The problem is:
I need to replace all the comments that starts with `//` with `/* */` comments 
I have already done this but i have a simple problem, in some files i have `//` comments into `/* */` comments like the example below:

```
/*

// some comments
code;
code;

*/
```

So when i went to substitute that with the script it appears like that:

```
/*

/* some comments */
code;
code;

*/
```

But the final `*/` of the father comments gives me an error because there cannot be two `*/` concatenated  so the last `*/` gives me an error.

I need to replace only the comments that aren't just in a `/* */` comment
and replace the `//` inside them with a single `/*`

```
for file in $(ls $path)    
do         
sed -i -e '/\/\// s/$/ *\//g' -e 's/\/\//\/* /g' $path/file       
done
```

Comment: What is a "bash ksh script"?

Comment: Its a Bash script formatted for a KornShell emulator

Comment: That's why script.ksh and not script.sh

Comment: ksh is ksh, bash is bash. They are shells, but a different ones. Bash specific syntax will not work in ksh and ksh specific syntax will not work in bash. `for file in $(ls $path)` is strange, [why you shouldn't parse ls output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [for i in ls bash pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: I'm new to this, but when i encounter a problem if i search my problem for Bash and i saw solutions for it, it works fine for my ksh

Comment: @KamilCuk it works for me like that, but if you know a better method i will be grated to know that. I've done a loop because i need to format more then one file.

Comment: I think the problem is complex enough to be solved with something else like perl, if you want I can submit a perl solution. Anyway I think it can be done with sed but the result is likely unreadable.

Comment: Is perl a native command ? I can't install tool because i work on a workmachine and the system cannot be modified

Comment: @MarioEsposito check it with perl -v

Comment: Ok, i have it. v5.10.1

Comment: Can you provide any info on the Kornshell emulator you're using? Sorry, I can't help on the `sed` problem. Good luck!

Comment: If the system cannot be modified, then you cannot edit the file as you propose.  If you have write access to a directory, you can (usually) install perl there without "modifying the system".

Comment: I don't know `Pro c`, and I'm not following your description, soooo ... how about updating the question with a section that shows the desired output?

Comment: what happens to `//` that appear inside string constants?

Comment: And should we think about edge cases like `// a double slash comment with /* in it` ?

Comment: Is an `awk` soltuion also OK? That can handle multi-line conditions better than `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Perl script should do the job for every file it gets as a parameter.

```
use v5.10;
for my $file (@ARGV) {
    -f $file or warn "$file is not a plain file, ignoring..." and next;
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    my @content = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
    my $comment = 0;
    for (keys @content) {
        $comment or $content[$_] =~ /\/\*/ and $comment = 1;
        $comment and $content[$_] =~ /\*\// and $comment = 0;
        $comment or $content[$_] =~ s/\/\/\s*(.*?)\s*$/\/\* $1 \*\// and $content[$_].="\n";
    }
    open $fh, '>', $file;
    print $fh @content;
    close $fh;
}
```

To execute it insert the contents into a file and write in the ksh command line.

```
perl <name_of_script>.pl <files>
```